# Getting an Error Trying to run OpenAi Gym on NChain-v0

Tags: python, openai-gym

Thank you in advance. I have installed Python 3.9.13.
Here's the code I'm running and the error right below it.

```
import gym

class Agent():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def play(self, env):

        # Reset the enviroment before play begins
        env.reset()

        # Play the game until it ends after 1000 steps
        end_game = False
        while not end_game:

            # Choose action 0 or 1 with 50% probability
            action = env.action_space.sample()

            # Perform the action
            state, reward, end_game, _ = env.step(action)

            # Print the latest information tho the terminal
            print("Took action {}, entered state {} and received reward {}.".format(action, state, reward))


# Create the Nchain-v0 env
env = gym.make('NChain-v0')

# Create an intelligent agent
agent = Agent()

# Play the game
agent.play(env)
```

** And Here's the error I'm getting**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jma/Documents/ML/1_play.py", line 27, in 
env = gym.make('NChain-v0')
File "/Users/jma/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 569, in make
_check_version_exists(ns, name, version)
File "/Users/jma/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 219, in _check_version_exists
_check_name_exists(ns, name)
File "/Users/jma/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 197, in _check_name_exists
raise error.NameNotFound(
gym.error.NameNotFound: Environment NChain doesn't exist.